# Is that friction sound from brake pads when spinning rear wheel normal?

Tags: brakes

This is with the hand brake off. I heard the brakes self adjust, but isn't that excessive? Is the parking brake overtightened? Please see the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJ1awOjk3QM

Both rear wheels are like this, and the front wheels make almost no sound when spinning, but all spin about as freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal ? Yes and no.
It is expected when your brake calipers, especially the pistons are dirty.

When these pistons get too dirty from brake dust and maybe a little bit of oxydation, they won't be able to come back to their neutral place as freely.

Right now it is not too concerning but you should at least spray a good amount of brake cleaner on the pistons to try and free them a bit.
If you feel you're able to try, try to unbolt your calipers and clean them with brake cleaner and a toothbrush (used one, don't go brush your teeth with brake dust! )

Even better ? Get a brake rebuild kit for both rear calipers and install them. But that takes some know how I'm not sure you have right now.

In any case, that is not dangerous right now after a good spray of brake cleaner.
It would be a good occasion to make sure your brake pads are in good shape at the same time !

Comment: This is not an answer I expected. How do you know it is not the overtightened hand brake though?

Comment: I do not, do you ? Or were you just waiting for that answer ?
To me, the fact that the wheel moves freely means that it is only an issue of brake pads still in contact with the wheel but not under pressure (hence the no issue cable thought).
Did you just buy the car ? Cables don't tighten themselves usually, quite the opposite actually.
Try and spray some good brake cleaner, which can only be good for your car and see if it helps. :)

Comment: Yes, I bought it used and this was the first time I checked the wheels. I feel I need to learn more about the brakes and I can't find anything in depth on the net.

Comment: Tried loosening the handbrake, did not help, so I guess you are right.